# Calculations are not processed in the background?

Tags: objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I have a void method that is being executed in background mode through the command NSQueue:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(go) object:nil];

    [queue addOperation:operation];


    -(void)go{

    ...
    NSArray *idt = ....//Have 276 records
    int show = 0;
    float frist = 0.00;

    for(int x=0;x<[idt count];x++){

        int idtcount = [idt count];
        frist = x / idtcount * 100;

        NSLog(@"Frist -> (%d / %d) * 100 = %.2f",x, idt.count,frist);


    }

    }
```

As you can see I'm doing a loop in the background function, assuming that the array called 'idt' has 276 records, I wonder why I'm doing the calculation:

```
frist = x / idtcount * 100;
```

Always returns me the value 0? I realized this command on table test and it worked, why it does not work here? how to solve this?

Comment: If you're trying to use Objective-C you should already know C, or at least Java, and should be familiar with the difference between integer and floating point arithmetic.  *Please* learn how to program in some other language before you attempt to use Objective-C or you will learn all sorts of things wrong.  The world can wait another 6 months for that big viral app you're planning to write.

Comment: @hot licks how is that in any way helpful??

Comment: @ConorLinehan - It's the best advice that one can give under the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

All your values appear to be integers which is causing integer division try casting one of them to a double
first = (double) x / idcoubt * 100